# "Result Change" vs "Value Change"

Tags: unreal-engine4

Concerning BT decorators

I really don't understand the difference,

```
On Result Change: Reevaluate only when the condition has changed.

On Value Change: Reevaluate only when the observed Blackboard Key changes.
```

**condition is based on blackboard key** so where is the difference ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

If, for example, you have a float key, and the condition is `>= 5.0`, then a change of the key from `3.0` to `4.0` would trigger a re-evaluation if set to `On Value Change` but not `On Result Change`.

Comment: but how does unreal knows which value correspond to a node self abort ?